# What utility can add a delivered_to line to an email based on To: and Cc:?

Tags: email

**TLDR:** I need a utility that reads an email and looks at the To: and Cc: fields to find an email address from a list of knows addresses. If it finds one I want it to output the email with an extra `deliver_to:  <address>` envelope line.

**Background**

My ISP delivers all company mail to a "domain mailbox"/"Catch all" mailbox but doesn't record the envelope recipient anywhere. We have an exchange server receive from that mailbox (using a so called "POP3 connector") and distribute them to users mailboxes. Bcc'ed mail and mail from mailing lists gets delivered to a default mailbox. I'm replacing exchange and this is the only piece left. I can retrieve mails with getmail using `MultidropPOP3Retriever` but then getmail expects to find an envelope line with the recipients email address (e.g. delivered_to: xxx@yyy.com) which my ISP doesn't provide. So I have to do my best and recover it from To:/CC:.

Comment: Are you sure you have a multidrop mailbox. The getmail help *What is a "multidrop" mailbox? How do I know if I have one?* suggests you don't.

Comment: You are right @meuh, the MultiGuesser option described later in the documentation was almost perfect for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that my answer was in the extensive getmail documentation. I need to use what getmail calls `MultiGuesser`.

However since in my case my ISP was adding a line like this in the envelope headers:

```
for <xxx@DOMAIN.com>
```

and since MultiGuesser is not perfect (e.g. it can't guess right if the recipient is bcc'ed) I finally implemented the original idea of adding `delivered_to` lines. I kept the MultiGuesser just in case my ISP stops adding this helpful line. The utility is a bash script that uses `formail` (suggested by dirkt in his answer). It isn't fast because it creates temp files for every mail it processes but it works fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Reads email from stdin and prints it to stdout with a twist:
# If it finds a line like " for <xxx@yyyy.zz>" in the envelope
# it will assume it refers to the receipient and will add a "Delivered-To"
# envelope line that will make getmail happy. -- Nick Demou 2018

# bash options for safety in case of errors
set -euf -o pipefail

# read stdin to temp file
cat - > /tmp/deliver.to.$$
logger -p mail.info "getmail, filtering via temp file /tmp/deliver.to.$$"

formail -X "" < /tmp/deliver.to.$$ > /tmp/deliver.to.$$.env
# logger -p mail.info "getmail, extracted envelope/headers to /tmp/deliver.to.$$.env"

ID=`grep 'SMTP id ' /tmp/deliver.to.$$.env 2>/dev/null| head -1|sed -e 's/^ *//'` || ID=UNKNOWN
# logger -p mail.info "getmail, extracted ID $ID"

ADDR=`grep '^ *for <.*@domain\.com>' /tmp/deliver.to.$$.env 2>/dev/null|head -1|sed -e 's/^.*<\([^>]*\)>.*$/\1/'` || ADDR=UNKNOWN
# logger -p mail.info "getmail, extracted delivery address $ADDR"

if echo $ADDR | grep -q '^[^@]*@domain.com *$' ; then
        cat /tmp/deliver.to.$$ | formail -A "Delivered-To: $ADDR"
else
        cat /tmp/deliver.to.$$
fi
logger -p mail.info "getmail filtered mail for $ADDR, $ID"

rm /tmp/deliver.to.$$
rm /tmp/deliver.to.$$.env
```

My `getmailrc` contains a filter like this which calls the above script:

```
[filter-1]
type = Filter_external
path = /opt/envelope-add-delivered-to.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

If "utility" means "shell scripting for the sender/receiver", have a look at [formail](https://linux.die.net/man/1/formail). For automatic processing of received mail on a per-user basis, have a look at [procmail](https://linux.die.net/man/1/procmail).

If you are replacing the exchange server with a Linux mail server, you'll probably want to do this within the server somehow.

Comment: Thanks dirkt, I found a shorter workaround but formail was a nice utility to learn about.

Comment: Again thanks @dirkt: I was forced to implement the requested functionality of adding an envelope header and formail was just perfect for the job.